# Is possible do things when user leave from Socket.io connection?

Tags: node.js

I'm using node js and socket.io, I need to manage the users when they leave from application, what is the best practice to do this?

Comment: definitely there should be `disconnect` method in which you can do something

Comment: I saw in the example below, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log(socket.id);
  });

  socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log(socket.id);
  });
});
```

You can get the socket.id when users enter and leave from your app.
I hope it is useful